# Remove of extra curly brackets with 0 index in json object

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, object

Here I want to remove one curly brackets and one zero in the json object .

I have tried a lot ,but did n't succeeded .

Below I am posting my codes ,please have a look .

```
{
  "responseCode": 200,
  "status": "success",
  "statusReason": "Home Details",
  "result": [
    {
      "branch_details": {
        "0": {  //this 0 index and one curly bracket
          "company_company_id": "12345",
          "company_name": "AVIS",
          "company_image": "uploads/avis.png",
          "company_gps": "12.3499,39.41454",
          "company_address": "dfdfhf",
          "company_phone": "8951177685",
          "company_rating": "0",
          "branch_id": "1234",
          "branch_name": "avis1",
          "branch_image": "uploads/avis.png",
          "branch_gps": "12.3499,39.41454",
          "branch_address": "eredfdf",
          "branch_phone": "6745745456465",
          "branch_rating": "0"
        },//this curly bracket
        "car_details": [
          {
            "car_id": "123",
            "name": "audi",

          },
          {
            "car_id": "14782",
            "name": "bmw",

          },
          {
            "car_id": "14781",
            "name": "nano",

          },
          {
            "car_id": "14783",
            "name": "bmw",

          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "branch_details": {
        "0": {//this 0 index and one curly bracket
          "company_company_id": "12345",
          "company_name": "AVIS",
          "company_image": "uploads/avis.png",
          "company_gps": "12.3499,39.41454",
          "company_address": "dfdfhf",
          "company_phone": "8951177685",
          "company_rating": "0",
          "branch_id": "1478",
          "branch_name": "hertz1",
          "branch_image": "uploads/company2.png",
          "branch_gps": "12.3499,39.41454",
          "branch_address": "sfgsdfg",
          "branch_phone": "sdfgsdfgsdgf",
          "branch_rating": "0"
        },//this curly bracket
        "car_details": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here I want to remove a pair of curly bracket and one zero index ,but I am unable to make it .

Codes

This code is inside a for each ,i posted some part of it.

```
$this->db->select("IFNULL(company.company_id,'') as company_company_id,IFNULL(company.name,'') as company_name,IFNULL(company.image,'') as company_image,IFNULL(company.gps,'') as company_gps,IFNULL(company.address,'')as company_address,IFNULL(company.phone,'')as company_phone,(select IFNULL(avg(rating),0) from company_rating where user_id='$user_id'  and delete_status ='false' )as company_rating,IFNULL(branch_id,'') as branch_id,IFNULL(branch.name,'') as branch_name,IFNULL(branch.image,'') as branch_image,IFNULL(branch.gps,'') as branch_gps,IFNULL(branch.address,'')as branch_address,IFNULL(branch.phone,'')as branch_phone,(select IFNULL(avg(rating),0) from branch_rating where user_id='$user_id'  and delete_status ='false' )as branch_rating");

$this->db->from("branch");
$this->db->join("company","branch.company_id=company.company_id");
$this->db->where("branch.branch_id",$branch_id);
$this->db->where("branch.delete_status" , "false");
$this->db->where("company.delete_status" , "false");
$tempquery111 = $this->db->get();

$temp1['branch_details'] = $tempquery111->result();


$this->db->select("IFNULL(car_id,'') as car_id,IFNULL(name,'') as name,IFNULL(image,'') as image,IFNULL(model,'') as model,IFNULL(price,'')as price,IFNULL(year,'')as year,IFNULL(type,'')as type,IFNULL(`no_of_seats`,'')as `no_of_seats`,IFNULL(`gear_type`,'') as `gear_type`,IFNULL(color,'') as color,insurance,status,IFNULL(description,'') as description,(select IFNULL(avg(rating),0) from car_rating where user_id='$user_id'  and delete_status ='false' )as rating");

$car_details = $this->db->get_where("cars",array("cars.branch_id" =>$branch_id ,"delete_status" => "false"));
$temp1['branch_details']['car_details'] = $car_details->result(); 

array_push($tempquery11,$temp1);
```

Can any one suggest something ?

Comment: So where is `$tempquery11` created?

Comment: I am doing array pushing ,here is some requirement ..@RiggsFolly

Comment: I would say that the `"0": {....}` that you want to remove is actually the array index of the first branch detail. I would guess that if you have another branch in the array then it will be preceded by `"1": {....}`   I don't know this language so can't help in detail but suggest you may be better accepting this and concentrating on the consumer of the JSON where it would be easy to pre-process to extract the branch detail in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter when querying the db,  `result()` will return an array (even if there is only one result) and `row()` will return a single row.

<s>Try changing  `$car_details->result();` to  `$car_details->row();`</s>

Apologies, I misread the json object. I should have said to change

`$tempquery111->result();` to `$tempquery111->row();`

EDIT:

Try set your array like this.

If it works for company_company_id it will work for the whole piece, you will just need to do the same for each.

```
$temp1['branch_details']['company_company_id'] = $tempquery111->result()->company_company_id;
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but for the life of me I cannot think of it right now.

Comment: But its showing some errors like .
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: @sradha Hmmm - I have updated my answer, it should resolve the issue, but I don't think it is the best way to do it. Hopefully someone else might weigh in.